# Secure programming in dynamic languages

Tags: security

Mistakes in memory management in C, C++, and their ilk are well known. I mostly program in dynamic, weakly typed languages. Are there issues which are particularly important in languages of this type? What language specific issues might I keep an eye out for?

I'm generally mindful of standard security issues, and try to think about the ways in which code could be misused, but am sure there are plenty of less superficial mistakes I could be making, and am interested in expanding my knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 2):

If you use anything similar to eval() then there is risks for attacks, esp if you are trusting something from outside your application.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you're not writing the lower level code doesn't mean that the language you are using, and therefore your app, wont have these kinds of security problems. So my answer to your question is to ensure that you stay up to date on the latest releases on whatever tools you are using. This is more of an issue for you if you host the environment in which your app run, otherwise it's more of a problem for users of your app if they have to run it on their machines.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a common attack which doesn't depend on type management. Generally, missing input validation is a very common reason for security issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of JavaScript the main vulnerabilities according to the **EC-Council Secure Programmer Vol.1** are the following:

> [Cross Site Scriptting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS). In a XSS
>   attack, attackers submit client-side
>   executable scripts by inserting
>   malicious Javascript, VBScript,
>   ActiveX, HTML or Flash into vulnerable
>   dynamic page and execute the script on
>   the user's machine to collect the
>   user's information.

**Avoiding XSS**:

Constrain Input:

- Define a codepage that decide wich characters are problemetic,
- Restrict variables to choose characters that are explicitly allowed.
- Filter metacharacters depending on the interpreter (HTML, browser and file system)

Aply canonicalization:
- The canonicalization technique brinbgs the input to an appropiate from before validating the input.

Validate de input:

- Validate all external input for field length, data type, range, and for a white list to ensure acceptance of onlyknown unproblematic characters.

Encode Output

- Convert metacharacters e.g: <, >, and "",use HTML entities instead.
- Encode user-supplied output so that any inserted script are prevented from being transmitted to users in an executable form.

> [JavaScript Hijacking](https://www.info-point-security.com/open_downloads/alt/JavaScript_Hijacking.pdf): Allows an
>   unauthorized party to read
>   confidential information. Occurs
>   because most web-browsers that
>   implement a security model do not
>   anticipate the use of Javascript for
>   communication. JavaScrpt Hijacking is
>   generally carried out through
>   cross-site request forgery. Coss-site
>   request forgeryis an attack that
>   enables the victim to sumbit one or
>   more HTTP requests to a vulnerable
>   website. This attack compromises data
>   integrity and confidentiality, meaning
>   an attacker can read the victim's
>   information and modify the information
>   stored on the vulnerable site.

A Javascript **Hijacking** attack can be defended:

- By declinig malicious requests.
- By preventing direct execution of the JavaScript response.

Comment: Excellent! This is more the type of feedback I was hoping for.